# Status-bar has disappeared when I'm testing my app on device using the latest Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Status-bar has disappeared when I'm testing my app on device using the latest Xcode. Is this normal ? I'm about to submit my app to appstore

Answer (score 0):

I had something like that, once, after update to ios 10. Try restart your device. If all goes well, so it is not your problem.